# React Context not updating for class as value

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a context that using a class instance as context value. After I updated the class instance. The change doesn't reflect in the consumer. Consumer still get the old class value. Can someone point me the direction of how to achieve this?

```js
// Service class
class Service {
   name = "oldName"
   function changeName(newName){
       this.name = newName;
   }
}

//Context provider
function App() {
  const service = new Service();
  return (
    <ServiceContext.Provider value={service}>
      <Home />
    </ServiceContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Then I try to change the name attribute of this service in one component.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const service = useContext(ServiceContext);
  const onClick = () => {
    service.changeName('newName')
    console.log(service.name) //here the name has updated
  }
  return <button onClick={onClick}>Change</h1>;
};
```

And try to get the updated value from the component.

```js
//Context consumer
import React, { useContext } from "react";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const service = useContext(ServiceContext);

  return <h1>{service.name}</h1>;
};
```

but in another consumer. service.name didn't get update. May I know why is that?

Comment: Can you show how you are changing the name?

Comment: This code won't compile, you should fix it first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how React works, it is not a "real reactive", just because you changed a value it doesn't mean the component will re-render.

The only way to cause a re-render is to use React's API.

See [Rendering a Component in docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component).

```
class Service {
  name = "oldName";
  changeName(newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }
}

const service = new Service();

// Provider
function App() {
  const [, render] = useReducer(p => !p, false);
  return (
    <ServiceContext.Provider value={{ service, render }}>
      <SomeComponent />
    </ServiceContext.Provider>
  );
}

// Usage
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { service, render } = useContext(ServiceContext);
  const onClick = () => {
    service.changeName("newName");
    render();
  };
  return <button onClick={onClick}>{service.name}</button>;
};
```

[image: Edit charming-bardeen-bdg01]

Comment: this looks good. thanks. 1) I forget to initiate the Service outside the component. 2) need something to trigger re-render