# React useState value in Context API always use initial value instead of updated value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state, use-context

I'm using Context API to store global value like userId to share between components across entire application.

Here's what the context.js looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const AppContext = React.createContext({
    date: new Date(),
    userId: null,
    groupId: null,
    setAppContext: () => {},
});

export const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
    const initState = {
        date: new Date(),
        userId: null,
        groupId: null,
        setAppContext: (appContext) => {
            console.log(state); // this line always log initial state value after first update
            setState({ ...state, ...appContext });
        },
    }
    const [state, setState] = useState(initState);
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={state}>
            {props.children}
        </AppContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AppContext;
```

Basically I'm trying to use one big context to hold all value that I use together and access them in child components like this:

```
// access value and the setter
const { userId, setAppContext } = useContext(AppContext);

// setting value
setAppContext({
    userId: newUserId,
});
```

The problem is, "state" variable in the setter function doesn't seems to update and when I try to set new value like above, other values get overwrite with its initial value (e.g. userId get update but the rest return to null), which I guess I must do something wrong and I still have no idea.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In this case:

```
const AppContext = React.createContext({
    date: new Date(),
    userId: null,
    groupId: null,
    setAppContext: () => {},
});
```

`setAppContext` is just a function, **it is not from React API**.

In order to change state, and make React to be aware of its change, you need to use any setter function from React API.

> Like setter function returned from `useState()`.

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62262840/7882470).

So, in your case, to solve it you need to pass a real setter:

```
const initState = {
  date: new Date(),
  userId: null,
  groupId: null,
};

const AppContext = React.createContext();

export const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initState);

  const setAppContext = (appContext) => {
    console.log(state);
    setState({ ...state, ...appContext });
  };

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ ...state, setAppContext }}>
      {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default AppContext;
```